# How to save email to a location with a delivery method="network"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, smtp

In my web config can i do setting delivery method=network and still it get saved in specifiedPickupDirectory or for that i need to always write a different application?

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="">
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="" password="" port="25" userName="" />
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\SentMail" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="25" />
    </smtp>

    <!-- Use this setting for development

    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Temp" />
    </smtp> -->
</mailSettings>
```

Took from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2006/04/23/Migrating-from-System.Web.Mail-to-System.Net.Mail.aspx).

Comment: Here i have to write an another application to forward the saved emails, but i want to use delivery method Network and want to save email too at a location, in a specified directory...

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet-That's not possible.